# use ANY with OVER (PARTITION BY ...)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

For example I have the following data:

```
select *
into t1 
from (
          select 'apple' as company, 'Tom' as people
    union select 'apple' as company, 'Jessi' as people
    union select 'fb' as company, 'Alex' as people
    union select 'fb' as company, 'Nick' as people
) as a

select * from t1
```

the data looks like:

```
company     people
apple       Jessi
apple       Tom
fb          Alex
fb          Nick
```

I want to see if each company has Tom - at each row level.

Is there something similar to:

```
   select *,
        any(people = 'Tom') over (partition by company order by company) as find_tom
    from t1
```

---

A work-around:

```
-- step 1: binary indicator has_tom
select *
    ,case when people = 'Tom' then 1 else 0 end
    as has_tom
into t2
from t1

-- use max(has_tom) to see if tom exists for each partition
select *,
    case when max(has_tom) over (partition by company order by company) = 1 then 'has tom' else 'no tom' end
    as find_tom
from t2
```

this yields the result I want:

```
company people  has_tom find_tom
apple   Jessi   0       has tom
apple   Tom     1       has tom
fb      Alex    0       no tom
fb      Nick    0       no tom
```

Comment: I can't do it with only one table reference, but it is simple with two references to the table, e.g. `SELECT t1.*, IsNull(t2.HasTom, 'No Tom') FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (Select Distinct Company, 'Has Tom' as HasTom from t1 WHERE people = 'Tom') t2 ON t1.Company = t2.Company`. There may be some sneaky way to do this, but I really think you need two table references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this helpful?

```
Select t1.*,
 CASE WHEN 
    MAX(CASE WHEN people='Tom' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OVER(Partition by company Order by (select null))  =1 THEN 'has Tom'
 ELSE 'no Tom' END
FROM t1
```

SQl Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ad91/19

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `case` like this:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when sum(case when people = 'tom' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by company) > 0
             then 'has tom' else 'no tom'
        end) as find_tom
from t1;
```